# How do tensorboard get gpu utilization?

Tags: tensorboard

We use tensorboard to analyse GPU details after a training task or something else, and it will always base on log files. I'm just wondering how do tensorboard (or the log file) get (or record) the GPU utilization. There is no explain online about this. Is it just record or watch the `nvidia-smi` time after time in a loop, and finally calculate the mean value?
[GPU utilization in tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnVz2.png)

Or if someone could guide me the documents, please.